# Dealing with enums when interfaces are in separate project

Tags: c#, architecture, interface, enums

I have the following projects in a Visual Studio solution for an application:

- Common - Utility methods and extensions
- Entities - Rich Domain objects with business logic specific to instances
- Repositories - Data Repositories
- DataServices - Thin wrapper to Repositories, contains business logic not specific to an instance
- Interfaces - All interfaces for entities and repositories

The reason I put the Interfaces into a separate project is avoid circular project references. This allows two projects to reference a common interface avoiding having both reference the project with the concrete implementation.

I've purposely made no project references in the Interfaces project to avoid circular project references. I create an Interface for classes defined in other projects, this allows me to reference the object interface, opposed to the concrete implementation in other interfaces.

So an example would be:

```
namespace Acme.Entities 
{
   public class Person : IPerson
   {
       string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
namespace Acme.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Acme.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITeam
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        IPerson Leader { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

The issue I've run into is when an Interface references an enum defined in another project. Without moving the Enums under the Interfaces project, I'm not sure how to reference the Enums without creating project references, for example:

```
namespace Acme.Entities 
{
   public enum Status
   {
       Unknown =0,
       Active = 1,
       Active = 2    
   }
} 

namespace Acme.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        Acme.Entities.Status ActiveStatus { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

The Acme.Entities.Status will fail unless I reference the Acme.Entities project, but that will create a circular reference because Acme.Entities references the Interfaces project.

Comment: Why are you opposed to moving the enum to the Interface project?

Comment: I've got to go with @DStanley here. You probably want to rename your `Interfaces` project to `Common` though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll either have to move the enum definition to the Interfaces project or to a separate project that both projects reference.

I personally would keep them in the same project - having a separate project just for enums seems like overkill.

Comment: Leaning towards putting the enums and interfaces into the same project, any suggestions on a name for the project since "Interfaces" wouldn't fully describe the project anymore?

Comment: "Common", as @MichaelPerrenoud mentioned, seems to be a sensible choice.

Comment: "Domain" would be my first choice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that your basic data types (including `enum`s, `interface`s, and `class`es) should all be in one project. Thus, your `Interfaces` project should include this `enum`, and any other data types that are common (maybe `abstract` base types). `Entities` should continue to have implementation-specific items that extend and/or use the base things in `Interfaces`. It might also make sense to merge `Interfaces` with your `Common` project, since common logic and common data often go together.

Comment: I run into the same problem if I put the interfaces into the Common project, because I don't references other projects in Common to avoid the circular reference issue.

Comment: Interfaces, enums, and classes definitely. I'm not so sure about abstract classes, though. You still have to test any implementation inside the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your components and interfaces in a correct way then you will never get this problem.

I suggest first review your code and your application architecture with this two principles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Domain Driven Desgin ---> Very importent rules:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

I agree also with that you have to move the SHARED Enums to a common IConstants.cs. Enums are nothing else than constants;

Comment: "Enums are nothing else than constants" They're more than just constants.

Comment: @DStanley This is a philosophical comment some ppl do not accept that and other see enums as collection of consts and the other do not do that because they can apply operation on Enums etc. I will not engage in this discussion.